# Define struct in the heap with different sizes

Tags: c++, c, heap-memory, biginteger, multiprecision

I am trying to implement a bigInt library. I have been checking other libraries like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/), [ttmaht](http://www.ttmath.org/) or [libtommath](https://github.com/libtom/libtommath) but any of them fulfill the requirements of the project (because licenses, because they only use the stack, etc)

I will follow the approach of libtommath (really well documented and written all in C) but I want all stored in the heap. libtommath implements bigInt in an structure like this one:

```
typedef struct  {
    int used, alloc, sign;
    mp_digit *dp;
} mp_int;
```

As you can see it has an indirection for accessing the values. (mp_digit are the digits of the big integer). I want to get off the indirection so have some kind of similar struct in the heap where the last element is a mp_digit[] where the size can be different for each instance of mp_int.

I could do it using void* and malloc() knowing that the first X positions are int's with information (used, alloc, sign, etc) and then access to the mp_digit[] knowing the offset but I do not like this idea. I wonder which would be a better approach.

I found other similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956697/c-define-arrays-in-struct-with-different-sizes) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43361176/c-same-structure-different-size?noredirect=1&lq=1) but they do not store all in the heap so mine is a bit tricky/different.

Thank you,

Comment: Please pick one language.

Comment: change `mp_digit *dp;` to `std::vector<mp_digit> dp;`  remove `used` and `alloc`

Comment: As an example of defining and using such structure you can look at [`LOGPALETTE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145040(v=vs.85).aspx) ([some usage example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45319996/how-to-construct-a-gdi-bitmap-object-from-a-device-dependent-hbitmap/45337644#45337644)). Basically you just allocate buffer holding struct itself immediately followed up by array of items.

Comment: Your desired ints can't be used as local variables.

Comment: @juanchopanza I am going to compile it with a C++ compiler so if we can use some of the benefits/abstractions of C++ it is good. If I have to write this part of the application as a C developer I have no problem with it.

Comment: @RichardCritten It would have an indirection if I use std::vector...

Comment: @JomsDev Ok use a template structure like std::array then

Comment: @RichardCritten using std::array means knowing the size of each array at compile time. This is not what I need. Sorry

Comment: Then you have an _"XY problem"_ you want dynamic memory but don't want to use the heap.

Comment: @RichardCritten Maybe I expressed it wrong. I want to use only  the heap

Answer (score 2):

In **C**, `mp_digit dp[]` will mean a *flexible array member*. This appeared in C99:

```
typedef struct  {
    int used, alloc;
    signed char sign;
    mp_digit dp[];
} mp_int;
```

You can allocate memory with `malloc(sizeof(mp_int) + alloc * sizeof(mp_digit));`; also with realloc.

However there is an obscure thing that might help you save a byte or two here depending on the type of `mp_digit` - namely, the offset of `dp` isn't necessarily `sizeof(mp_int)` but might be less; there is a kludgey macro hack for calculating the *actual* minimum size to allocate (yet this is still portable).

That definition doesn't work in C++, but you could use a pointer to an incomplete type in C++.

---

Notice that a flexible array member **is not compatible** with an 1-byte array such as in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145040(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

in C something like this to create

```
mp_int *LN_Create(int ndigits, int allocate)
{
    mp_int *ln = calloc(1, sizeof mp_int);

    if (ln != NULL)
    {
        ln->ndigits = ndigits;
        if (allocate)
        {
            ln->dp = calloc(ndigits, sizeof mp_digit);
            ln->alloc = 1;
            if (ln->dp == NULL)
            {
                free(ln);
                ln = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    return ln;
}
```

or

```
mp_int *LN_Create1(int ndigits)
{
    size_t allocsize = sizeof mp_int + (ndigits - 1) * sizeof mp_digit;
    mp_int *ln = malloc(allocsize);

    if (ln != NULL)
    {
        memset(ln, 0, allocsize);
        ln->ndigits = ndigits;
    }
    return ln;
}
```

Comment: This is completely pointless as it requires 2 allocations and indirection is not removed.

Comment: it is something what OP asked. I do not comment his needs. Fields of the structure show exactly what he wants.

Comment: He wrote "want to get off the indirection", your code shows basically the same thing that he's already got.

Comment: did not notice this sentence